# Is there a datasheet for the Canon 24-105mm diaphragm unit?

Tags: canon, specification, diaphragm

Does anyone know if a datasheet is available for the Canon 24-105mm diaphragm unit? I'm wondering if there's a way to use an Arduino or suchlike to control the diaphragm via the flex cable, but I can't find any specs or datasheets anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

NB: this answer was written when the question was asking about the shutter, rather than the diaphragm. It may be deleted soon.

There is no shutter in the 24-105; almost every camera system smaller than medium format has a focal plane shutter in the body, rather than a leaf shutter in the lens. The only exception I know of is the Pentax Q system.

Comment: Really? Huh. What exactly is this, then? https://youtu.be/WtsW9Hwa4UY?t=121

Comment: That's the diaphragm which controls aperture, not the shutter which controls exposure.

Comment: Ugh, brainfreeze. Apologies, I'll reword the question.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I could find to this by googling was a "Pick and Place" blog article where the author describes what he's discovered about the EF-S mount connections:

https://pickandplace.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/canon-ef-s-protocol-and-electronic-follow-focus/

It looks like you send signals on D<sub>IN</sub>'s rising edge (D<sub>IN</sub> is the middle of the five small contacts), and controlling the diaphragm involves sending the $07$13 opcode, along with a two-digit hexcode value for the specific aperture setting you want.  Opening it up to wide open uses the opcode $13$80.

I think. I could be wrong. I just did a quick google. :)